# Linq join 4 list <T>

Tags: c#, linq, list, join

i have 4 list that  I need to join together

```
public class Person
{
    public int personid { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int depid { get; set; }
    public string departmentname { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public int groupid { get; set; }
    public int depid { get; set; }
    public string groupname { get; set; }
}

public class UploadFile
{
    public int fileid { get; set; }
    public int personid { get; set; }
    public int groupid{ get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
}

List<Person> Persons=GetPersons();
List<Department> departmentlist=getDepartments();
List<Group> grouplist=getgroups();
List<UploadFile> filelist=getFiles();
```

I need an output like:

```
fileid   fname        filename   path                         

1        samplename   Mydoc      departmentname+">"+groupname
```

Comment: If these get function are from the same database I would suggest doing the joining using Linq2SQL or entity framework rather than in memory.

Comment: We ain't doing your homework for you. Show us your code, explain what problem you're encountering and then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Zip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
List persons=GetPersons();
List departmentlist=getDepartments();
List grouplist=getgroups();
List filelist=getFiles();

var result = persons.Zip(departmentlist, (person, department) => person.fname + " " + department.departmentname)
                    .Zip(grouplist, (personAndDepartment, group) => personAndDepartment + " " + group.groupName);

// etc ...
```